# Hook only specific post type

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, filters, hooks

with this function I change the title of my posts in the posts type 'alternatives'. My problem is that Wordpress changes all my titles now. Does anyone know how I can set this for the specific custom post type only?

```
// Change alternatives title
function alternatives_title( $title, $post_id ) {
    if( get_post_type( $post_id ) == 'alternatives' ) {
        $title = $title . ' alternative';   
    } 
    return $title;
}
add_filter( 'the_title', 'alternatives_title' );
add_filter( 'get_the_title', 'alternatives_title' );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the [number of arguments your filter accepts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter#Parameters):

```
add_filter( 'the_title', 'alternatives_title', 10 /* Priority */, 2 /* Arguments */ );
```

And you only need to use `the_title` (there is no `get_the_title` filter).